# Laravel eloquant belongsToMany get records belongs to relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

I'm using many to many relationship with **products** and **product_categories** tables using **product_product_category** pivot table.

Product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function product_categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategory::class, 'product_product_category');
    }
}
```

ProductCategory model

```
class ProductCategory extends Model {

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_product_category');
    }

}
```

What I need to do is when **I supply an array of categories need to get products only with these categories.** This is my code

```
$selectedCategotries = array(1, 2);
$products = Product::with(['product_categories' => function($q) use ($selectedCategotries){
    $q->whereIn('product_categories.id', $selectedCategotries);
}])->get();
```

But I **get all the products instead**. It will be a great help if you can supply a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer with **whereHas**. Adding the answer for anyone who come up with the same issue.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('product_categories', function ($q) use ($selectedCategotries) {
    $q->whereIn('product_categories.id', $selectedCategotries);
})->get();
```